# findElement from a previously filtered page returns the same result

Tags: java, selenium

So I have this code (I hope this narrows it down enough):

```
List<WebElement> resultList = driver.findElements(By.className("result"));
for (WebElement item : resultList) {
     String rating = item.findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'result-rating')]")).getAttribute("class");
    (...)
```

Let me break down what I think I'm doing:

First I'm separating the nodes that interest me into a list of webElements.
Then I'm cycling through item by item, and trying to get the div element under that item whose class starts with result-rating.

The problem is I always get the same value for rating, which is the first one. If I print out the values I get inside my for, they're right. But when I try to filter it further (3rd line), that particular value always comes up the same.

But how, if each item of my list contains a different node? How can they all have all the page code to return the first only?

And most importantly... how to fix what I'm doing to get the respective rating for every record?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: Well, the findElement in the third line is a single statement, I don't know if I'd be able to see what's going on behind it. But yes, if I print out the elements inside my for, they're all the nodes I need. Only the rating is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right, you are first trying to get a list of items by classname("result") and then iterating for each item in list to find an element whose class starts with "result-rating" and then get it's class attribute. If that's the case then you may try below.

```
    List<String> resultRatingList = resultList.stream()
        .map(element -> element.findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'result-rating')]")).getAttribute("class"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi, maybe I failed to explain what the actual issue is (thanks for the suggestion, though, looks really elegant). But here's the deal: If I do a System.out.println on the values inside my for, they're right. It's just the code in the 3rd line, filtering for the class, that actually fails and always returns the same value (from the first element).